# Django reset password bypass when the user is authenticated

Tags: django

I'm following [this](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.in/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html) blog for Django password reset. It uses `# url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace="auth")),` for the urls.

Now when the user is logged-in, ie `is_authenticated`, then these urls should not work.

There's no use of links such as `password_change`, or `password_reset` when the user is already logged in. How can I disable those urls when user is authenticated?

Comment: Surely the only time those urls are of any use is when you are logged in?

Comment: Ohh my bad. Well, those links also contain `recover` , `forgot password` urls which doesnt make sense to be browsed when the user is logged in?

Comment: The changing password requires you to enter the current password. If you've forgotten your password, then you need to reset it. Therefore the reset password urls are useful, even when you're logged in.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're trying to solve here, that wouldn't be an option a user would try to take unless they needed the functionality